# How to pass and read parameters while php.exe compile process on Windows (cmd)

Tags: php, windows, parameters, cmd

When I use web browser I pass parameters by this way:

`http://localhost/script.php?nr=444524`

and get it this way:

`$var = $_GET('nr');
print_r($var);`

but how to achieve the same result (pass and get parameters) when I compile same script with cmd on windows?

> c:\php.exe script.php ?nr=444524

this way doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way.  `$_GET` is a variable created to feed in data from an HTTP request.

On the command line you enter arguments as:

```
php script.php 444524
```

From here you can ready the arguments as `print_r($argv);`.

Answer (score 0):

All the words you put into the command line, starting with the script name can be found in the global variable `$argv`. Launch your script with various parameters and check the output of `print_r($argv);` to see what you get.

Check the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)